# Are there any ideas as to what the English landscape was like before the arrival of the Angles?

Tags: middle-ages, britain, geography

I am not sure if this question is within the guidelines (it may be), but I am curious as to this: In North America, for instance, it is often said it was heavily forested and that a squirrel could get from one side unto the other without touching the ground.

Comment: This question seems to imply  that the Angles (and presumably the Saxons & Jutes that came with them) had a dramatic effect on the landscape upon their arrival. I'm not sure that this is the case.

Comment: Well, the ænglisc did seem to build their houses mostly from wood and thatch out of worship, so I would assume at least that there would be a decent amount of trees cut down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Angles, along with the Saxons and the Jutes, probably started arriving in Britain around the middle of the 5th century, some 50 years after Rome abandoned its northern-most province. They would have mostly seen a landscape with many features of the late Roman period (described below) in a state of decay, alongside Celtic Iron Age dwellings.

By the time the Romans arrived in Britain, much of England was already deforested though there were significant [regional differences](https://humanities.exeter.ac.uk/media/.../Fields_of_Britannia_interim_3.pdf) *(this link is a download)*, ranging from around 15% forested area in central England and East Anglia to around 40% in upland northern England (largely modern-day Cumbria). Farming was both arable and pastoral with most people living in Iron Age-style roundhouses, which were made of timber and thatch, dotted across the landscape of much of England.

[image: Iron Age Roundhouse]

*Source: Chris Gunns [CC BY-SA 2.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons*

> The [landscape the Romans found](http://www.english-heritage.org.uk/learn/story-of-england/romans/landscape/) was one of cultivated fields and
>   pastures, scattered farmsteads and settlements, and surviving islands
>   of managed woodland.
>
> The Romans eventually criss-crossed this landscape with roads, beside
>   which many villages and towns developed. These often had rectangular
>   houses and shops fronting onto the road.

[image: Remains of a Roman villa, Oxfordshire]

*The remains of a Roman villa at North Leigh, Oxfordshire. Early Anglo-Saxons would probably have seen more than this as, over the centuries, people removed stones to construct churches, walls and houses. (Image is [Copyright Richard Croft](https://www.geograph.org.uk/photo/5141756) and licensed for reuse under this Creative Commons Licence.)*

Probably no more than 10% of a population estimated to be between 2 to 3.5 million would have been ‘agriculturally non-productive’ during the late Roman period. This would have declined as

> Towns and villas were falling into ruin within a generation [of the
>   Roman departure]. It can be argued that the Anglo-Saxons, who arrived
>   in numbers some decades later, came into a political and cultural
>   vacuum – although many of the people were apparently still there,
>   farming the landscape, albeit probably in smaller numbers.

*Source: The British Museum, '[Roman Britain](https://www.britishmuseum.org/PDF/british_museum_roman_britain.pdf)'(pdf)*

It is also believed that the population declined during the centuries following the Roman departure, perhaps by as much as half. Further,

> With the disappearance of the Roman system the population of Britain
>   would have reverted totally to a subsistence agriculture mode. We may
>   thus expect for the area that is now England to find a settlement
>   pattern made up of farmsteads for nucleated or extended families
>   practising agricultural strategies designed to yield little in the way
>   of surplus above that necessary to perpetuate the crops and herds.

*Source: A.S.Esmonde Cleary, '[The Ending of Roman Britain](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Ending_of_Roman_Britain.html?id=GW1fOaFFHiMC&redir_esc=y)'*

However,

> Squatter occupation..... seems to have continued in a number of towns
>   and it is a measure of the skill of Roman planners and engineers that
>   only two major Roman urban sites are unoccupied today, Silchester and
>   Wroxeter...

*Source: Michael Reed, '[The Landscape of Britain](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Landscape_of_Britain.html?id=npKDfDGC4-0C&redir_esc=y)'*

[image: Roman Britain AD 410]

*Source: Lotroo / R. Botek; Изработено от Потребител:Lotroo (Own work) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons*

The Roman road network,on the other hand, would have been evident:

> One important survival was the road network, which formed the skeleton
>   of communications in Britain until the 18th century.

*Source: The British Museum, '[Roman Britain](https://www.britishmuseum.org/PDF/british_museum_roman_britain.pdf)'(pdf)*

When the Angles, Saxons and Jutes started to settle, the generally accepted view is

> the taking-over by the Anglo-Saxons of a Romano-British site or social
>   feature and its adaptation the better to respond to Anglo-Saxon
>   priorities.

*Source: A.S.Esmonde Cleary*

In practice, this meant that many buildings were either (1) torn down so the materials could be used elsewhere, (2) put to some other use or (3) simply abandoned.

---

*Other sources*

*P. H. Sawyer, '[From Roman Britain to Norman England](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/From_Roman_Britain_to_Norman_England.html?id=WpwOAAAAQAAJ&redir_esc=y)' (2nd edition, 1998)*

*Simon T. Loseby, '[Power and Towns in Late Roman Britain and Early Anglo-Saxon England](https://www.raco.cat/index.php/MemoriasRABL/article/view/23771)' (pdf)*

Comment: I think that answer is near abouts perfect, lovely! Thank you so much. Interesting, hardly any forested lands -- I couldn't imagine it being heavily forested.
I have been more interesting in the anglo saxons lately, and I was wondering as to what many believe they may have seen and such that goes with that.

Comment: For comparative purposes, 10% of England is woodland (March 2017) according to https://www.forestry.gov.uk/forestry/infd-7aqknx so there has been quite a lot lost since the 5th century (though not as much as most people imagine).

Comment: Growing up in history classes, which seem to paint things in a very biased light and/or had probably more wrong or misunderstood information that right, always seemed to depict struggles for resources, like trees, in their colonies, almost as if every mother country had become like Easter Island.

Comment: That could be because of your age! :) Archaeology and technology have led to some major revisions over the past 20 to 30 years so if you were at school in the 1980s or earlier you probably can't blame your history teacher for that.

Comment: I was later than the 80's, but for sure it's just biased perspectives. I am not saying that false material outweighs the true.

Comment: I would really like to know why someone downvoted this. If there is something wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Remember, Saxons and the Jutes arrived in Britain in the year 411, just a year after last Roman troops (of usurper Constantine) had left to help in the sieges of Arles. The Roman Empire was an absolute mess since in Dec 26, 406 many germans had crossed the frozen river Rhine.