# The squirrel which could cross an entire realm jumping from branch to branch

Tags: ancient-history, spain, ecology

The metaphor (or meme) of the squirrel that could cross an entire territory without touching the ground is very old and, [as far as the Iberian Peninsula is concerned, is attributed (maybe wrongly) to Strabo](https://books.google.es/books?id=4Zo3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=strabo%20squirrel&source=bl&ots=XSt9vCZkvV&sig=lowaNavd8qoDqJrfkvBBNRqFqH8&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSgp_5kbbXAhWJ1hoKHQhjBqoQ6AEIRzAI#v=onepage&q=strabo%20squirrel&f=false).

[image: Strabo's squirrel crossing Iberia]

[I have just learned that this meme was also used to describe the ancient North America](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/are-there-any-ideas-as-to-what-the-english-landscape-was-like-before-the-arrival), and by googling, I found references of the squirrel crossing ancient Gaul and Britain.

What is the first documented use of this meme? To what territory was it applied the first time?

Comment: He probably wasn't the origin of the memes you mention, but in Norse mythology, Ratatoskr was the squirrel that carried messages between the different worlds of the World Tree.

Comment: "references of the squirrel crossing ancient Gaul and Britain" - can you cite one or two of these references?